# Задача на циклы в Питон

Tags: python, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, каким образом здесь происходит итерация и было бы здорово взглянут на код, так как новичок в этом плане

Comment: Ну, `for i in range(a, b + 1):` или типа того наверное?

Comment: хотелось бы взглянуть на полный код

Comment: Взглянуть или украсть, выдав за своё собственное решение?

Comment: ну хорошо, можете не писать ваше право, но у меня таких задач сейчас 6 штук, хотя бы на одно решение взглянуть и по аналогии как-то двигаться

Comment: в чем ошибка не подскажите ?    a1 = int(input("введите t="))
a2= int(input("введите d="))
a3 = int(input("введите y="))
a4 = int(input("введите x1="))
a5= int(input("введите xh="))
a=min(a1,a2)
b=max(a1,a2)
print(a)
print(b)
T=0
for i in range(a,b+1,1): 
 xi = a4 + a5 
 term = 3*xi-a3 
 T+=term 
x1=xi
print(T)

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь в чём-то ошибка?

Comment: Но как минимум можно сходу сказать, что вычисление `xi` не соответствует условию задачи

Comment: @andreymal попробовал трассировку сделать например для  t=2 
 d=3 
 y=4 
 x1=5 
 xh=6   вышло T=76 возможно я ошибаюсь

Answer (score 3):

Псевдокод на псевдопитоне, чтобы не писать за вас решение:

```
тут вводим через input всё, что по задаче нужно ввести
вычисляем а
вычисляем б
сумма = 0

тут цикл от а до б:
   тут считаем очередное слагаемое суммы
   сумма += очередное слагаемое

печатаем сумму
```

Comment: спасибо, только как быть с условием  a=min(t,d), b=max(t,d) ?

Comment: @РонРонов ну вот ровно так в коде и написать